# PHP equivalent for Java's toCharArray()

Tags: java, php

In Java, I use toCharArray() to convert a string to an array of chars like follows:

```
String s1= "\nX\\nT_$\u0061\"\'";
char[] c1 = s1.toCharArray();
System.out.println((Arrays.toString(c1) ));
```

The result will be:

```
[                           
, X, \, n, T, _, $, a, ", ']
```

if you notices the first item is a new line, while the second \n was not considered a new line because the double back slashes is considered as one.

Also, it takes care of unicode representations like \u0061

Is there any equivalent function for PHP?

Comment: str_split does not work as expected. Try the same string above and compare the results.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`str_split()`](https://www.php.net/str_split): this returns an array of the characters.

Example:

```
$s1 = "\nX\\nT_$\u0061\"\'";
$char_arr = str_split($s1);
print_r($char_arr);
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not the same output I get from java's function:

Comment: @PyQL because PHP's internal representation of strings and Java's differ? FWIW, Java uses UTF-16 internally

Answer (score 2):

In php you can simply use a string similar to an array:

```
   <php
     $string ="abc";
     echo $string[0];
```

It is not an array, but you can use array access. So no reason for toCharArray

Comment: What if you needed to split the string into pieces of 2?

Comment: @AmalMurali The question asked for an equivalent to `toCharArray()`... splitting into pieces of two seems like a separate question

Answer (score 2):

OK, after a little research, I stumbled upon this.

First: [this link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) tells us that:

> A string is series of characters, where a character is the same as a byte. This means that PHP only supports a 256-character set, and hence does not offer native Unicode support. See details of the string type.

And we learn in the detail section that:

> Given that PHP does not dictate a specific encoding for strings, one might wonder how string literals are encoded. For instance, is the string "á" equivalent to "\xE1" (ISO-8859-1), "\xC3\xA1" (UTF-8, C form), "\x61\xCC\x81" (UTF-8, D form) or any other possible representation? The answer is that string will be encoded in whatever fashion it is encoded in the script file.

Ouch.

Also, earlier in this section we also learn that:

> There are no limitations on the values the string can be composed of

What that means ultimately though, is that there is no strict equivalent to Java's `.toCharArray()`. Save for writing your PHP script in... UTF-16 (!), but even then, splitting the string will return bytes.

It seems the closest to what you want is to use [`mb_convert_encoding`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) to change to UTF-16, followed by [`mb_split`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php).

Comment: This should be accepted as valid answer since it gives further detail about how string is processed in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

use `str_split()`

this is php.net sample code

```
<?php

$str = "Hello Friend";

$arr1 = str_split($str);
$arr2 = str_split($str, 3);

print_r($arr1);
print_r($arr2);

?>
```

output

```
Array
(
    [0] => H
    [1] => e
    [2] => l
    [3] => l
    [4] => o
    [5] =>
    [6] => F
    [7] => r
    [8] => i
    [9] => e
    [10] => n
    [11] => d
)

Array
(
    [0] => Hel
    [1] => lo
    [2] => Fri
    [3] => end
)
```

Comment: it does not work with special chars, try the string above and compare the output to yours.